# Bootstrapp carousel with flip effect inside

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have some divs inside a bootstrap carousel. These divs are like cards, so when the user click on them it makes a flip effect. The problem is when the card do the effect, the card is cut becaouse of the limit of the div content. This is an example in jsfiddle:

```
//Any ideas how to solve it?
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pctnpzc5/

Comment: The problem is not clear enough. What do you wish to solve?

Comment: When you see the flip effect clicking on the card, you can't see the corners of the card doing the effect because this card is inside the carousel and it's is hidding part of the effect. The complete effect is showed here https://nnattawat.github.io/flip/

Comment: Don’t weasel your way around the limitation that you can only post jsfiddle links when you also show some code by inserting pseudo comments like `//Any ideas how to solve it?`

Answer (score 1):

you need to give your card a bit of space either by reducing the with of the card or increasing the container size (or both).

```
.card-flip{
    height: 350px;
    width: 80%; margin:10px auto;
}
```

(here we give 10% margin on left and right and 10px on top and bottom)

like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ten0g56s/

Comment: Thanks! But do you think there is another option if I don't wanna change the card witdh?